# Updating Multiple rows in 1 query call . Parse.com

Tags: iphone, ios, parse-platform

I have to update multiple records in a table on parse.com. It is related to change message status from unread to read in multiple records. 
This is the example to update a single record.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];

// Retrieve the object by id
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"xWMyZ4YEGZ" block:^(PFObject *gameScore, NSError *error) {

// Now let's update it with some new data. In this case, only cheatMode and score
// will get sent to the cloud. playerName hasn't changed.
[gameScore setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"cheatMode"];
[gameScore setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1338] forKey:@"score"];
[gameScore saveInBackground];

}];
```

How to update multiple records?

For more clarification,I have to execute query something like : 
**Update tableName SET messageStatus = 'read' Where userId = 'someId'**

Any help ?

Answer (score 3):

First you should query these objects:

```
NSArray *arrayOfMessageIDs = @[@"2314312", @"312432423"]; // An array of your desired messages' ID
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Message"];
        [query whereKey:@"messageID" containedIn:arrayOfMessageIDs];
```

Then you iterate through them and update their status.
After that you save all the array.

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
                return;
            }
            for (PFObject *message in objects) {
                // Update your message
            }
            int success = [PFObject saveAll:objects];
            NSLog(@"Status %@", success? @"updated successfully": @"update failed");
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a big number of records I suggest you to execute the update via cloud code. What you need to do is to query and receive a list of records then iterate through the list, update the records and then save the records.

you can find information about cloud code at https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide.

Comment: Will this cloud code work on IOS ? Actually i want the rows to be updated by code from ios. Is that feasible ?

Comment: Thank you for your help,I will check for your suggestion, but i am looking for the query or some other way by which i can update the records at once , same as we do in sql query.

Comment: There is no such way for now. Sorry.